# Convert FD to Handle

Tags: linux, haskell, tty

I'd like to open a pseudo-tty and use the resulting slave terminal to connect to stdin/stdout on a subprocess. `openPseudoTerminal` gives me an `IO (System.Posix.Types.Fd, System.Posix.Types.Fd)`, which I sought to translate into a pair of handles using `fdToHandle` in `GHC.IO.Handle.Fd` (GHC specific, but I couldn't find another such function). However, I get the following:

```
liftA (fdToHandle *** fdToHandle) openPseudoTerminal
Couldn't match type `System.Posix.Types.Fd'
               with `System.Posix.Internals.FD'
```

Any ideas how I convert between these two (presumably similar) things?

For bonus points, this will give me an `IO (IO Handle, IO Handle)` - is there a neat way to convert it to an `IO (Handle, Handle)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`openPseudoTerminal` is in the unix package, which also provides an `fdToHandle` with the appropriate type in `System.Posix.IO`.

I'll throw in the best one-liner I have come up with so far, to deal with the pair of `IO Handle`s:

```
getHandles :: IO (Handle, Handle)
getHandles =
  openPseudoTerminal >>= uncurry ap . (fmap (,) . fdToHandle *** fdToHandle)
```

or:

```
getHandles =
  openPseudoTerminal >>= uncurry (ap . fmap (,)) . join (***) fdToHandle
```

Answer (score 3):

You can ask GHCI for information about these types --

```
>> :i FD
type FD = Foreign.C.Types.CInt
>> :i Fd
newtype Fd = Fd Foreign.C.Types.CInt
```

so they are essentially identical, except that one is a `newtype` and the other is a `type`. So the conversion functions are (I recommend choosing better names)

```
convert :: FD -> Fd
convert = Fd

convert' :: Fd -> FD
convert' (Fd x) = x
```

RE your question about converting from `IO (IO Handle, IO Handle)` to `IO (Handle,Handle)` you could do this explicitly

```
flatten :: IO (IO a, IO a) -> IO (a,a)
flatten x = do
  (a,b) <- x
  a'    <- a
  b'    <- b
  return (a', b')
```

but a better way would be to avoid creatign the `IO (IO Handle, IO Handle)` in the first place. Since your types are

```
openPseudoTerminal :: IO (Fd, Fd)
fdToHandle         :: FD -> IO Handle
```

you could do

```
getHandles :: IO (Handle, Handle)
getHandles = do
  (Fd a, Fd b) <- openPseudoTerminal
  a'           <- fdToHandle a
  b'           <- fdToHandle b
  return (a', b')
```

Comment: Both types are instances of `Num` and `Integral`, so you can convert back and forth using `fromIntegral`.